# How to select all text quickly in a Tera Term Pro window?

Tags: terminal, mouse, selection

I am using Tera Term Pro version 2.3.

I am hoping to select all then [Alt+C] to copy.

I tried using [Ctrl+A] or [Alt+A] but it doesn't work.

There is no "Edit > Select All" menu option.

I have no choice but to use the left mouse button and drag all the way.

It takes some minutes to scroll through all the text, while I hold down the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider logging. Once the data has been displayed, open the log file in an editor that does allow select all and copy commands.

Documentation for Log Tab.
http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/menu/setup-additional.html

Comment: Thanks, I just downloaded the latest version Tera Term 4.79 from the website. It does allow selecting all text.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging won't help after everything gets copied on the terminal. So
Press mouse lift button and move to the direction where the content is to copy and press ctrl+PageUp. It won't select everything at once but make the select faster.